# Strike tag issue in firefox versus ie/chrome

Tags: html

I have been given some html that look like this (I have no control over the html):

```
<p>Some text</p>
<strike>
  <p>This is some text</p>
</strike>
<p>More text</p>
```

The text shows as strikeout in both IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox. I have added `display:inline-block` to the `<p>` tag which fixes Firefox but then breaks IE and Chrome.

Is there a solution to this which will work in all three browsers and does not involve changing the html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is due to nesting a `block` element (`<p>`) inside of an `inline` element (`<strike>`).

This CSS gets the `line-through` working in the nested `<p>`:

```
strike p {  /* only applies to <p> tags that are children of a <strike> tag */
    padding: 0;                     // remove default spacing from <p> tag
    text-decoration: line-through;  // fixes missing line-through
}
```

**Note:** Only tested in Firefox 3.6.x

Comment: +1 for addressing the cause. `strike` seems to work fine in FF by itself.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I just need a big dope slap :)

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS.

Tailored to your specific HTML example:

```
strike p
{
 text-decoration: line-through;   
}
```

JSFiddle (verified to work in IE9, Chrome 10, FF4): http://jsfiddle.net/hcYVv/1/

Answer (score -1):

That tag is not universally supported. Use the following CSS

```
.strikethrough { text-decoration: line-through;}
```

and then accordingly change your html to

```
<p class="strikethrough">This is some text</p>
```

Comment: I have no control over the html, so I can't add a class to those paragraph tags. I guess I could make a style that did though....